# On the existence of a functional linear $\varphi: L^{\infty}([-1,1])\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\chi:[-1,+1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function of interval $[0,1]$, *i.e.* 
$$
\chi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 &\mbox{if} & x\in [0,1]\\ 0 &\mbox{if} & x\notin [0,1]
  \end{array}\right.
$$
I would like to prove that there is a continuous linear functional $\varphi: E=L^{\infty}([-1,+1])\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

- $\|\varphi\|_{E^\ast}=2 $,
- $\varphi(\chi)=1$,
- $\varphi(f)=0$ for all $f$ continuous.

**My attempt.** Let $G\subset L^{\infty}([-1,+1])$ of sectionally continuous functions in $L^{\infty}([-1,+1])$.   I tried to define $\varphi$ in G by  putting $\varphi(g)=\varphi_+(g)-\varphi_-(g)$ for 
$$
\varphi_+(g)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}g(t)\quad \mbox{ and } \quad \varphi_-(g)=\lim_{t\to 0^-}g(t).
$$
Then I try to use the Hahn-Banach theorem to extend the functional $ \varphi$ from $G$ to $L^\infty([-1,1])$. But I have no control over the norm of $\varphi $.

Comment: Doesn't Hahn-Banach guarantee that the norm is the same?